# What are the uppercase and lowercase conventions for folder names in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have just started with ASP.NET MVC. One thing that puzzles me is why some default folder names are written with a capital and why others are in lowercase. I just don't see the logic of it. To be specific, why is it that in MVC the Content folder is with a capital C and the subfolder theme is written in lowercase. Are there any naming conventions in place here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Content folder holds things like css stylesheets, javascript, images, etc. The themes folder are css files for the default theme with jQuery UI. These traditionally use [lowercase conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html).

Comment: Ah, so that means that anywhere else the convention would be to user folder names written with a capital. Also in de Content folder. Okay, that works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, I suppose it's accurate to say use the casing convention of the language you're working in, even in mixed-language environments/applications. So if it's C# source, use that convention. If it's Javascript, use that convention. Since it looks like you're a new user, can you accept this answer if it answers your question. It improves the site for everyone.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how to accept an answer to the question. It turns out you have to click on the check image on the left, next to the answer. Well, done that.

Comment: Why uppercase for content? What's the reasoning? When I moved some classes to a "Task"-folder, the "System.Threading.Tasks"-Task was no longer found. VS thought "Task" was referring to the folder, not a class. So why would I ever use uppercase folder names?